# Regular expression for two fields on JSON response - Jmeter

Tags: regex, json, jmeter

Suppose I have this JSON response:

```
    [
     {
      "id": "15",
      "userId": "1",
      "new": "true",
      "date": "08/12/2013",
      "text": "…"
     },
     {
      "id": "16",
      "userId": "1",
      "new": "false",
      "date": "08/12/2013",
      "text": "…"
     }
    ]
```

The regular expresión extractor for the **id** of every object would have the following configuration:

```
    Reference name: object
    Regular Expression: "id":"(.+?)"
    Template: $1$
    Match No: -1
    Default value: null
```

What I need is to extract both **id** and **new** from each object, to use them together in a ForEach controller. I need some help with the regular expression for this case.

```
    Reference name: object
    Regular Expression: ¿? "id":"(.+?)" ¿? "new":"(.+?)" ¿?
    Template: $1$$2$
    Match No: -1
    Default value: null
```

Also, how do I reference each specific part of the **object** varible? **${object_1}** and **${object_2}**?

**Edit**: sorry, I forgot to mention I´m specificaly using Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup:

[image]

[image]

And then use either a ForEach Controller or if you only need some values then you will have:

> id_1=15
>
> id_2=16
> ...
> new_1=true
>
> new_2=false
> ...

Indexes are related.

Otherwise you can have a look at this:

- http://www.dzone.com/links/extract_json_content_efficiently_in_jmeter_using.html

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON. So, why not parse it as JSON then.
It's quite simple this way. I've used the **[org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)** Java parser.

```
String jsonData = "[\r\n" + 
        "        {\r\n" + 
        "         \"id\": \"15\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"userId\": \"1\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"new\": \"true\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"date\": \"08/12/2013\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"text\": \"…\"\r\n" + 
        "        },\r\n" + 
        "        {\r\n" + 
        "         \"id\": \"16\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"userId\": \"1\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"new\": \"false\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"date\": \"08/12/2013\",\r\n" + 
        "         \"text\": \"…\"\r\n" + 
        "        }\r\n" + 
        "       ]";

JSONArray jsonRoot = new JSONArray(jsonData);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoot.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonRoot.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("Object_" + (i+1) + " = id: " + jsonObj.getString("id") +
            ", new: " + jsonObj.getString("new"));
```

***Output** :*

```
Object_1 = id: 15, new: true
Object_2 = id: 16, new: false
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I was using Jmeter. I'm sorry!

Comment: @Alex, my apologies for missing the tags. I'm sorry too!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a screencast for the very subject, if that helps. Check it out.

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-744b552e-c91e-4db2-9d39-37c6e66f22ac/t/jmeter-tutorial-json-array-extraction